# Extra field in wp_post instead of postmeta

Tags: posts, database

Is there any advantage in terms of query performance, if I add an extra fields in `wp_posts` table, instead of using postmeta?

I have already searched for these reasons, but without success.

Comment: Not really the same question but close enough to give you some hints: [Is it bad practice to create own table for a plugin?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53932/is-it-bad-practice-to-create-own-table-for-a-plugin) and [Should I use custom post types or a custom database tables for plugin development?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/47915/should-i-use-custom-post-types-or-a-custom-database-tables-for-plugin-developmen)

Answer (score 0):

This is extremely broad question. Query performance depends on what you are querying and how efficiently MySQL server can perform that, using indexes available. You can have wildly inefficient query on one table, just like you can have perfectly fast one against meta.

In general WP development the typical practices go (in popularity descending):

1. Making use of native database schema
2. Introducing new indexes
3. Introducing new tables
4. Modifying native tables